Should we have a rendering tag?
We seem to have a variety of questions that are related to creating 3d-renders of LEGO models and parts.  There is a lighting that we have on 11 questions so far, but a render tag would be more generalized and might encompass more questions.  What do you think?

There seems to be some confusion between the usage of the lighting tag for  rendering virtual models and lighting for electronics.
I have removed that tag for the former and have replaced it with a new rendering tag, I have also added the new tag to a few other questions that match the criteria but feel free to tag any other questions that match.

That's awesome. Thanks Ambo100!

Its a topic that comes up also in lots of other lego-related boards so I'd say yes
